# how to pass child state to the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I try to figure out how I can pass the child(DatePickerComponent) state to the parent(Locations) component.

I passed the date as parameter in this.props.callBackFromParent. I wonder how I can read that date parameter in my parent component.

```
  class DatePickerComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          date: moment()
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      //local state change
      handleChange= (date) => {

        const valueOfInput = date.format();
        this.setState({
          date: date
        });
        this.getChosenDate();

         alert("time is now " + valueOfInput);


      }

     getChosenDate = () =>{
      let chosenDate = this.state.date;
      this.props.callBackFromParent(chosenDate);
      console.log("time to try " + chosenDate);
     }


      render() {
        return <DatePicker
            customInput={<ExampleCustomInput/>}
            selected={this.state.date}

             onChange={this.handleChange} ...
```

parent component (Locations)

I try to make a callbackfunction where I can store the child state into a new parent state (Locations)

```
  myCallback = (dataFromChild) =>{
   this.setState({selectDatum:dataFromChild});
    alert(dataFromChild);

}

render(){

return(
  ...
   <MenuItem> <DatePicker callBackFromParent={this.myCallback} /> </MenuItem>
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Pass function to child which will receive parameters, then you can use that parameter in parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the ref property onto your child, eg childRef, and have a function in child, eg getState() that returns the state. Then, in parent you can use this.refs.childRef.getState().

```
<DatePickerComponent ref="childRef"/>
```

Then inside DatePicker:

```
class DatePickerComponent {
 ...

 getState() {
   return this.state;
 }
}
```

And in your parent:

```
this.refs.childRef.getState();
```

Comment: I get an error saying: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined" when I try to console.log( this.refs.childRef.getState());

Comment: Try adding that method into DatePickerComponent  component.

Comment: Yep I have wirtten the getState method in my DatePickerComponent
  getState(){
    return this.state.date;
  }